# Usage of LsaCallAuthenticationPackage from win32 api in Golang

Tags: go, winapi

i try to use LsaCallAuthenticationPackage in golang but not successful i don't know why. My exemple in C# is the Rubeus project:

```cs
              var ticketsPointer = IntPtr.Zero;
                    var returnBufferLength = 0;
                    var protocalStatus = 0;

                    var ticketCacheRequest = new Interop.KERB_QUERY_TKT_CACHE_REQUEST();

                    ticketCacheRequest.MessageType = Interop.KERB_PROTOCOL_MESSAGE_TYPE.KerbQueryTicketCacheExMessage;

                        ticketCacheRequest.LogonId = logonSessionData.LogonID;

                    
                    var tQueryPtr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Marshal.SizeOf(ticketCacheRequest));
                    Marshal.StructureToPtr(ticketCacheRequest, tQueryPtr, false);

                    retCode = Interop.LsaCallAuthenticationPackage(lsaHandle, authPack, tQueryPtr,
                        Marshal.SizeOf(ticketCacheRequest), out ticketsPointer, out returnBufferLength,
                        out protocalStatus)
```

So i try to reproduce in golang with my system call:

```golang
func LsaCallAuthenticationPackage(    
        lsaHandle LsaHandle, // HANDLE
        authenticationPackage uint32, // ULONG
        protocolSubmitBuffer uintptr, // PVOID
        submitBufferLength uint32, // ULONG
        protocolReturnBuffer *uintptr, // *PVOID
        returnBufferLength *uint32, // *PULONG
        protocolStatus *NtStatus, // PNTSTATUS
    ) error {
        r0, _, _ := syscall.Syscall9(procLsaCallAuthenticationPackage.Addr(), 7,
                                         uintptr(lsaHandle),
                                         uintptr(authenticationPackage),
                                         uintptr(protocolSubmitBuffer),
                                         uintptr(submitBufferLength),
                                         uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(protocolReturnBuffer)),
                                         uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(returnBufferLength)),
                                         uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(protocolStatus)),
                                         0, 0)
        return LsaNtStatusToWinError(r0)
}
```

i my call of this function :

```golang
//authPack & lsaHandle come from LsaLookupAuthenticationPackage
        protocolSubmitBuffer := uintptr(unsafe.Sizeof(ticketCacheRequest))
        protocolSubmitBufferLength :=  uint32(unsafe.Sizeof(ticketCacheRequest))
        var protocolReturnBuffer *uintptr
        var returnBufferLength *uint32
        protocolStatus := NtStatus(0)
        fmt.Println(&protocolSubmitBuffer)
        a := LsaCallAuthenticationPackage(lsaHandle,authPack,protocolSubmitBuffer,  protocolSubmitBufferLength ,protocolReturnBuffer,returnBufferLength, &protocolStatus)
        resultStatus := LsaNtStatusToWinError(protocolStatus)
```

but it not wor in don't know why i have this message : `Only part of a ReadProcessMemory or WriteProcessMemory request was completed.`. Anyone know why ?